# Python Pandas-retrieving values in one column while they are less than the value of a second column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a df that looks like this:

```
   posF  ffreq  posR  rfreq
0    10   0.50  11.0   0.08
1    20   0.20  31.0   0.90
2    30   0.03  41.0   0.70
3    40   0.72  51.0   0.08
4    50   0.09  81.0   0.78
5    60   0.09   NaN    NaN
6    70   0.01   NaN    NaN
7    80   0.09   NaN    NaN
8    90   0.08   NaN    NaN
9   100   0.02   NaN    NaN
```

In the posR column, we see that it jumps from 11 to 31, and there is not a value in the "20's". I want to insert a value to fill that space, which would essentially just be the `posF` value, and `NA`, so my resulting df would look like this:

```
   posF  ffreq  posR  rfreq
0    10   0.50  11.0   0.08
1    20   0.20  20     NaN
2    30   0.03  31.0   0.90
3    40   0.72  41.0   0.70
4    50   0.09  50     NaN
5    60   0.09  60     NaN
6    70   0.01  70     NaN
7    80   0.09  80     NaN
8    90   0.08  81.0   0.78
9   100   0.02  100    NaN
```

So I want to fill the NaN values in the position with the values from `posF` that are in between the values in `posR`.

What I have tried to do is just make a dummy list and add values to the list based on if they were less than a (I see the flaw here but I don't know how to fix it).

```
insert_rows = []
for x in df['posF']:
    for a,b in zip(df['posR'], df['rfreq']):
        if x<a:
            insert_rows.append([x, 'NA'])
print(len(insert_rows))#21, should be 5
```

I realize that it is appending x several times until it reaches the condition of being >a.

After this I will just create a new df and add these values to the original 2 columns so they are the same length.

If you can think of a better title, feel free to edit.

Comment: Will the value always be (index - 1)*10? Or is there some other convention you are using to interpolate those values?

Comment: is `posR` meant to be unique? Also, why does the row with `posR=31.0, posF=20` turn into a row with `posR=31.0, posF=**30**`?

Comment: Sorry, the values will not always be base10, they are positions output by another program that point to text in a long string. Pmende posR is missing a value between 20 and 30 so the value of 20 is inserted and 31 is shifted down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to retrieve the new indices for the entries in `posR` by interpolating with `posF` and then put the values to their new positions - but as you want to have `81` one row later than here, I'm afraid this is not exactly what you're searching for and I still don't really get the logic behind your task.
However, perhaps this is a starting point, let's see...

This approach would work like the following:

Retrieve the new index positions of the values in `posR` according to their order in `posF`:

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.interp(df.posR, df.posF, df.index).round()
```

Get rid of `nan` entries and cast to int:

```
idx = idx[np.isfinite(idx)].astype(int)
```

Create a new column by copying `posF` in the first step, and set `newrfreq` to `nan` respectively:

```
df['newposR'] = df.posF
df['newrfreq'] = np.nan
```

Then overwrite with the values from `posR` and `rfreq`, but now at the updated positions:

```
df.loc[idx, 'newposR'] = df.posR[:len(idx)].values
df.loc[idx, 'newrfreq'] = df.rfreq[:len(idx)].values
```

Result:

```
   posF  ffreq  posR  rfreq  newposR  newrfreq
0    10   0.50  11.0   0.08     11.0      0.08
1    20   0.20  31.0   0.90     20.0       NaN
2    30   0.03  41.0   0.70     31.0      0.90
3    40   0.72  51.0   0.08     41.0      0.70
4    50   0.09  81.0   0.78     51.0      0.08
5    60   0.09   NaN    NaN     60.0       NaN
6    70   0.01   NaN    NaN     70.0       NaN
7    80   0.09   NaN    NaN     81.0      0.78
8    90   0.08   NaN    NaN     90.0       NaN
9   100   0.02   NaN    NaN    100.0       NaN
```